# Snake Game -- Can't steer snake

Tags: java, swing, awt

**Actual question on the bottom of the post!**

At first, I want to explain my problem.

I'm writing a basic Snake game and I got the snake to move automatically. It moves automatically to the right of the window when you execute the code, just like intended. However, I can't steer my snake the way I want, it doesn't change its direction at all.

---

To avoid confusion, `player` is an instance of the class `Snake`.

---

To explain the movement of the snake:

The `Snake` object has a `coordinates` property which is an ArrayList holding `SnakePart` objects. Each `SnakePart` object has the property `x` and `y`. Using this ArrayList, the snake is moving by drawing little rectangles on a canvas by using the `x` and `y` properties on the y- and x-axis of the canvas.

The `Snake` object also has a `dx` and a `dy` property that gets added (or subtracted -- depending on the direction of the snake) to the `x` and `y` property of the `SnakePart` object to move the snake in a direction.

---

To update the ArrayList in `Snake.java`:

```
public void move() {
  SnakePart head = new SnakePart(this.coordinates.get(0).x + this.dx, this.coordinates.get(0).y + this.dy);

  this.coordinates.add(0, head);
  this.coordinates.remove(this.coordinates.size() - 1);
}
```

---

To draw the snake on the canvas in `Board.java` (partly, rest of the method is not necessary for now):

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  this.player.coordinates.forEach(snakePart -> {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
  });
}
```

---

To steer the snake, I want to use the arrow keys. Depending on which arrow key is pressed, the snake's `x` and `y` coordinates/properties get modified (`Board.java`):

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

  if (keyCode == 37) {
    this.player.dx = -10;
    this.player.dy = 0;
  } else if (keyCode == 38) {
    this.player.dx = 0;
    this.player.dy = -10;
  } else if (keyCode == 39) {
    this.player.dx = 10;
    this.player.dy = 0;
  } else if (keyCode == 40) {
    this.player.dx = 0;
    this.player.dy = 10;
  }
}
```

---

Whole code:

`Snake.java`:

```
package com.codef0x.snake;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Snake {
  ArrayList < SnakePart > coordinates;
  int dx = 10;
  int dy = 0;

  public Snake(ArrayList < SnakePart > coords) {
    this.coordinates = coords;
  }

  public void move() {
    SnakePart head = new SnakePart(this.coordinates.get(0).x + this.dx, this.coordinates.get(0).y + this.dy);

    this.coordinates.add(0, head);
    this.coordinates.remove(this.coordinates.size() - 1);
  }

  public void grow() {
    SnakePart newPart = new SnakePart(0, 0);
    newPart.x = this.coordinates.get(this.coordinates.size() - 1).x - 10;
    newPart.y = this.coordinates.get(this.coordinates.size() - 1).y;

    this.coordinates.add(this.coordinates.size() - 1, newPart);
  }
}
```

`Board.java` (showing only relevant parts, otherwise it would be too much code)

```
package com.codef0x.snake;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
  Snake player;
  ArrayList<SnakePart> snakeCoordinates;

  public Board() {

    this.snakeCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    snakeCoordinates.add(new SnakePart(150, 150));
    snakeCoordinates.add(new SnakePart(140, 150));
    snakeCoordinates.add(new SnakePart(130, 150));
    snakeCoordinates.add(new SnakePart(120, 150));

    this.player = new Snake(snakeCoordinates);

    this.food = new Food();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    clear(g);

    this.player.coordinates.forEach(snakePart - > {
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(snakePart.x, snakePart.y, 10, 10);
    });
  }

  public void clear(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getHeight(), getWidth());
  }

  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g) {
    paintComponent(g);
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == 37) {
      this.player.dx = -10;
      this.player.dy = 0;
    } else if (keyCode == 38) {
      this.player.dx = 0;
      this.player.dy = -10;
    } else if (keyCode == 39) {
      this.player.dx = 10;
      this.player.dy = 0;
    } else if (keyCode == 40) {
      this.player.dx = 0;
      this.player.dy = 10;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    return;
  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    return;
  }

  public void run(Board board) {
    Timer game = new Timer();
    game.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      boolean initiallySpawned = false;
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Graphics g = board.getGraphics();

        if (hitSomething()) { // removed method hitSomething, not relevant
          game.cancel();
          return;
        }

        player.move();
        update(g);
      }
    }, 0, 500);
  }
}
```

`SnakePart.java`:

```
package com.codef0x.snake;

public class SnakePart {
  int x;
  int y;

  public SnakePart(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

---

#### What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change to steer the snake properly?

---

In case you still want / need to see all files as a whole, you can have a look at them here:

[Snake.java](https://pastebin.com/inAw492i)

[Board.java](https://pastebin.com/1SHvKC2S)

[SnakePart.java](https://pastebin.com/QZatjRYM)

[Food.java](https://pastebin.com/V4x9xj1V) <- Not related, but may prevent confusion about the `Food` object

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? Does the snake respond at all? Have you checked to make sure that the keyPressed event is firing like you think it is? I would put System.out.println() statements in your movement code and validate that as you press keys it's flowing through the codepaths that you expect.

Comment: I would do key-typed or released rather than just key-pressed, but have you tried just printing or otherwise debugging  the grow method to see why dx is always moving "to the right"?

Comment: @Jazzepi I've used `System.out.println(this.player.dx + " " + this.player.dx)` to debug, but only in the `keyPressed` method where everything looked fine. Now I did it again, but this time I also added a `System.out.println(this.dx + " " + this.dy)` to the `move()` method in `Snake.java`. In `keyPressed` the outputs look like expected (after pressing key up `dx` went from 10 to 0 and `dy` from 0 to -10). But in `move()` `dx` is still 10 and `dy` still 0...

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sure the `grow()` method is not related to the problem because `dx` is sopposed to be moving to the right all the time, until changed via the arrow keys what doesn't work.

Comment: That's my point... It's not changing so it's always 10 within move and/or grow. If you set a breakpoint in each method and your key handler, what happens?

Comment: @CodeF0x Call System.identityHashCode(player) inside of the keyPressed method and the move method. I wonder if they're the same object. I'm hazy on threading semantics at the moment, but I feel like you might have two seperate objects. One inside the thread and one outside.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've set a breakpoint in `grow()`, but because it doesn't get called anywhere the debugger doesn't jump to `grow()`. In `keyPressed()` everything looks fine. But in `move()` I still have the same values as they would have never been modified by `keyPressed()`. The values somehow don't get updated.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the main.
You create a `board` to *host* your game status, and create different one to listen to the keyboard.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    Board board = new Board();
    frame.add(board);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.addKeyListener(new Board());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    board.run(board);
}
```

it should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    Board board = new Board();
    frame.add(board);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.addKeyListener(board);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    board.run(board);
}
```

Also `board.run(board)` has little sense, in the scope of `run` method, board can be swapped to `this` (and so omitted) ...

Comment: @minus Nice catch!